# Repeat whole tablix on every page in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two tablix in my report both having different datasets. I want first tablix to be repeated on every page. while in remaining space of the page tablix 2 will be displayed. Is this possible?

Comment: What determines pages? Are you using a list grouped by something to generate pages?

Comment: Its second tablix that determines pages(list grouped by something to generate pages). First tablix is like header of the page(i.e same data is repeated on every page.)and in remaining page list of table 2 is to be shown.