# How to repeat report items on subsequent pages?

Tags: reporting-services, pagination

I have a summary `Tablix` and a `Chart` at the top of my report, above the detail `Tablix`. I would like to repeat these summary and chart items on each page. I've tried setting `KeepWithGroup`, `RepeatOnNewPage` and `FixedData`, but they don't help.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39468224/722393), but unfortunately the question remains unanswered.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: How about adding them to the "page header"?

Comment: @WolfgangKais ~ Yes, I did try that. But the header won't accept a `Tablix`.

Comment: You can accomplish this by adding a row above your detail tablix and then dragging and dropping them into cells in that row.

Comment: @aduguid ~ Good tip. But when I do that, the summary `Tablix` picks up the `Dataset` from the detail `Tablix`. The field then becomes read-only, so it can't be changed. Does this occur for you as well?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there were different sources for each tablix.

Comment: @aduguid ~ I may have found a solution in [this](http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/). I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @aduguid ~ OK, I got this working—but not with the `Lookup()` function as previously hoped. In fact it was rather simple and I've ended up with a cleaner report. What I did was drop the Summary `Dataset` and move the logic into column expressions instead. This way both `Tablix`es can use the same `Dataset`. So I'd like to accept your suggestion—care to make it into an answer?

Comment: No worries, always glad to help a fellow SSRS developer :)

Comment: @aduguid ~ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [Nesting Data Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/nested-data-regions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) by adding a row above your detail tablix and then dragging and dropping the chart and summary tablix into cells in that row.

[image: video]